# Does set padding change view size on Android or IOS?

Tags: android, ios, css

I'm studying about how padding works and compare it among Android, IOS, Web.

[image]

In this situation. What number should I set to Item for width in each platform?

It would be helpful if you leave answer on your familiar platform(Web/Android/IOS).

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [the basics](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ON WEB:**

It depends on the `box-sizing` property of the element you are applying the padding to. This property can in effect have value `content-box` or `border-box` (can also have `initial` and `inherit` but again the first two will get applied in the end). With `content-box` the actual size is increased by padding and borders, with `border-box` not:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content-box {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box content-box"> Content Box </div>
<div class="box border-box"> Border Box </div>
```

When using `content-box`, the actual width of the rendered element will be the sum of `width`, `padding` and `border` property values. With `border-box` it will be equal to the `width` property. Paddings and borders visually stay "inside" of the defined `width` boundary in this case. You can read more about the differences here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

**CONCLUSION:**

You could either use `content-box` and `335px` width, or `border-box` with `375px` width for your example. Both are possible, although `border-box` is more intuitive and helps preventing errors in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

set your view width as match_parent

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="text" />
```